# std::string::erase is deleting all the characters following the iterator instead of only the iterator

Tags: c++, string, stl, find, erase

I am trying to erase a character from a string. I have tried the code below:

```
size_t it = s.find(char(i+97)); //dont mind the i, it is just the int in a for loop.
s.erase(it);
```

Here is a test case: 
Input: "cccaabababaccbc" 
Output: "ccc" 
Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: When you pass in an index, to erase, it goes till the end of the string. Change it to s.erase(it,1). The second parameter indicates the number of characters to remove. I suggest not naming the variable it, that name is typically used for iterator types.

Comment: @RehmaanMomin Thanks a lot, it works now. Could you post your comment as an answer if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in an index, to erase, it goes till the end of the string. Change it to s.erase(it,1). The second parameter indicates the number of characters to remove.

I suggest not naming the variable it, that name is typically used for iterator types.

If you pass an iterator to erase, then only that character is removed.

Heres the docs: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/